# How do I retrieve the values of unknown keys within unknown children?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database that looks something like this:

[image]

The children of `Entries` will have various unknown names and the keys/values within each of those children will also have various unknown names. I wish to retrieve all the child names and key names but am not sure how to double loop through the `DataSnapshot`. This is what I have been playing with so far:

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("Entries").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot entries : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (Map<String, String> entry : entries.getValue().entrySet()){
                    Map singlePair = (Map) entry.getValue();
```

I know those last two lines are a mess but I'm not sure how to retrieve the content of the children? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look that messy. Is it working?

Comment: No, the call to `entrySet` isn't valid for one thing but I didn't know how or what to try and call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer sticking to `DataSnapshot` classes longer and giving them more semantic names. Something like:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("Entries").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot entrySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      for (DataSnapshot propertySnapshot : entrySnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(propertySnapshot.getKey()+": "+propertySnapshot.getValue(String.class));
      }
    }
  }
  ...
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below code.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    database.getReference()
            .child("Entries")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        System.out.println(snapshot.getKey()); // home wifi, work computer, ...
                        Map<String, Object> map =(Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();

                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){

                            System.out.println(entry.getKey()); // network name
                            System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString()); // password

                        }



                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: This works, but Frank's solution above is the one I understand better. Cheers.